# Any relation between adsense lack of impressions and incorrect sitemap?

Tags: googlebot, google-adsense

I have recently submitted a sitemap in search console for at least 200 new pages on my site. However, I did a mistake by not including a slash ("/") at the end of each url. But the pages without slashes will redirect (301) to correct pages.

On these pages, I am seeing adsense slots going blank too often. I guess the issue is related to adsense crawler. Is the incorrect sitemap the culprit? (inspite of 302 redirects)

Comment: Just because slots don't get filled for you doesn't mean that they won't get filled for your users.  Much of the adverts are based on the person rather than the content of the site.   Google may also determine that only filling one slot on a page performs better in some cases compared to filling all the slots.   I don't think this is anything to worry about.

Comment: Hi, but if there were no matching ads, the space should collapse right?  But I am seeing a blank white space equal to the size of the ad. Is that normal behaviour?

Comment: That would depend on your settings in AdSense and your layout.     AdSense has a setting to collapse the space or not.   Even if AdSense collapses the ad space itself, your layout may have a fixed box around it that doesn't collapse.